# How to display radio buttons in line with css? Buttons not aligned properly in mozilla and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to CSS and have been trying to find the problem here. Radio buttons alignment is not proper in chrome and firefox where as it's workign perfectly well in explorer. I would greatly appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance![enter image description here][1]

```
#choiceContainer{width:160px;}
#lftChoice{float:left;width:70px;font-size:11px;vertical-align:top;}
#rtChoice{float:right;width: 90px;font-size:11px;vertical-align:top;}
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML code too?

Comment: Set their `line-height` to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because of `floats`. Try to take the float right div first and the float left after that and that shall resolve your issue.

**For Instance,**

```
<div id="choiceContainer">
    <div id="rtChoice"><!-- paste your code here --></div>
    <div id="lftChoice"><!-- paste your code here --></div>   
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lduf7/)**

Hope this helps.